# Example of Simple phase Change Using 2 Qubits

Tags: qiskit, programming, textbook-and-exercises

I need to manipulate phases in 2 qubits.  I will eventually create 34 distinct phase sets to map to an alphabet I built.

I see https://github.com/oreilly-qc/oreilly-qc.github.io/blob/master/samples/Qiskit/ch07_08_qft_rotating_phases.py

Is there a simple qiskit or qc example of a 2 qubit program that results in the following by using 45, and 90 degree phasing(see pic added)?:

As the letters change, so will each phase in each qubit.  Any help appreciated.    Here is the first "letter" (>)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand perfectly - you have 2 qubits, and where do you want to apply the phase? For example, you could have it as $$ |0\rangle + e^{2 \pi i k / 34} |1\rangle $$ where $$ k \in [0, 33] $$

Comment: Thanks C.  Looking for simple qiskit example that shows 2 quibit phase changes, specifically to the |0> of the first and second quibit.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example in braket form? I'm still a bit confused as to what you're asking for specifically

Comment: Thanks - I am looking for simple qiskit code to phase change 2 quibits.  I need 36 phase changes to a 2 qubit register.  Apologize for any confusion.

Comment: More specifically, what are the input vector states and the output vector states you want?

Comment: Two registries created:

reg1 = QuantumRegister(2, name='reg1')
reg2 = QuantumRegister(1, name='reg2')
qc = QuantumCircuit(reg1, reg2)


Input states reset to 0.

Output state:

reg1[0] = 45°
reg1[1] =  90°
reg2[0] = 0°
reg2[1] = 0°

(no superposition)

Once I have this simple "letter" will program others in qiskit.  Aplogize if this is not clear enough.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't really make sense. Can you use bra-ket notation? Simply having degree angles isn't descriptive enough, because all quantum states have a global phase that doesn't impact the state itself

Comment: On examining further it may be that state encoding will not be the best, nor will amplitude encoding to capture the different states I need to represent.  Maybe will use a simple vector to render the 36 states with minimal quibits.  Thanks for the ideas.